# How can i read through each line of a file and append it to a json file in python?

Tags: python, json

I've been trying to figure out a way to store proxy data in a json form, i know the easier way is to just take each proxy from the text box and save it to the file and then to access it i would just load the information from the file but i want to have groups that work with different types of IP's. Say for example one group uses the proxy IP from a certain provider and another group would use an IP from a different one, i would need to store the IP's in their respected groups which is why i think i need to create a json file to store each of the proxies in their own json array. What i'm having trouble with is adding the IP's to the json array as i am trying to loop over a transfer file with the IP's in them and then add it to the json array. As of now i tried this,

```
def save_proxy():
    proxy = pooled_data_default.get('1.0', 'end-2c')
    transfer_file = open('proxies.txt', 'w')
    transfer_file.write(proxy)
    transfer_file.close()
    transfer_file1 = open('proxies.txt', 'r')

    try:
        with open('proxy_groups.txt', 'r+') as file:
            proxy_group = json.load(file)
    except:
        proxy_group = []
    total = []
    for line in transfer_file1:
        line = transfer_file1.readline().strip()
        total.append(line)
    proxy_group.append({
        'group_name': pool_info.get(),
        'proxy': [{
            'proxy': total,
        }]
    }),
    with open('proxy_groups.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(proxy_group, outfile, indent=4)
```

This doesn't work but it was my attempt at taking each line from the file and adding it to the json array dynamically. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: this is what is being outputted:

```
[
    {
        "group_name": "Defualt",
        "proxy": [
            {
                "proxy": [
                    "asdf",
                    ""
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This was the input

```
wdsa
asdf
sfs
```

It seems that it is only selecting the middle one of the 3. I thought that printing the list of them would work but it is still printing the middle and then a blank space at the end.

An example of my data is the input to the text box may be

`wkenwwins:1000:username:password`

`uwhsuh:1000:username:password`

`2ewswsd:1000:username:password`

`gfrfccv:1000:username:password`

the selected group which i may want to save this to could be called 'Default'. I select default and then clicking save should add these inputs to the seperate txt sheet called 'proxies.txt', which it does. From the text sheet i then want to loop through each line and append each line to the json data. Which it doesnt do, here it was i expect it to look like in json data

```
[
    {
        "group_name": "Defualt",
        "proxy": [
            {
                "proxy": [
                    'ewswsd:1000:username:password',
                    'wkenwwins:1000:username:password',
'uwhsuh:1000:username:password'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So then say if i made 2 groups the json data txt file should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "group_name": "Defualt",
        "proxy": [
            {
                "proxy": [
                    'ewswsd:1000:username:password',
                    'wkenwwins:1000:username:password',
                    'uwhsuh:1000:username:password'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
[
    {
        "group_name": "Test",
        "proxy": [
            {
                "proxy": [
                    'ewswsd:1000:username:password',
                    'wkenwwins:1000:username:password',
                    'uwhsuh:1000:username:password'
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is so i can access each group by only calling the group name.

Comment: Can you give some examples to illustrate your description of the data?

Comment: @AMC added some examples

Comment: You should close the `proxies.txt` file before the first `with` block.  Also `f1 = check.readline()` is not necessary, you can directly use `line` instead of `f1`.

Comment: @acw1668 that works and it does print stuff out but it keeps over writing the last one because i keep on calling line, so whenever line updates it just rewrites it in the .txt. Is there a way that i can print one and then move onto the line and continue printing instead of over writing my data? Im editing the code in the question now to show how i cleaned it up.

Comment: You should 1) load/initialize `proxy_group` before the first `with` block; 2) update the `proxy_groups.txt` file after the first `with` block, i.e. move the second `with` block out of first `with` block.

Comment: @acw1668 how can i make it not print \n when taking it directly from the file?

Comment: Use `line.strip()`.

Comment: @acw1668 im not sure where i went wrong but lets say i put 3 inputs in, the file only shows 2 sets of proxys and also its not printing how i wanted it to, its making new groups for each proxy, i want it to print with one group for all the proxies in the entry box. Im going to edit my question now to be more precise and show exactly what is happening.

Comment: edited it @acw1668

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the `save_proxy()` as below:

```
def save_proxy():
    proxy = pooled_data_default.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
    # save the proxies to file
    with open('proxies.txt', 'w') as transfer_file:
        transfer_file.write(proxy)
    # load the proxy_groups if exists
    try:
        with open('proxy_groups.txt', 'r') as file:
            proxy_group = json.load(file)
    except:
        proxy_group = []
    proxy_group.append({
        'group_name': pool_info.get(),
        'proxy': proxy.splitlines()
    })
    with open('proxy_groups.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(proxy_group, outfile, indent=4)
```

The output file `proxy_groups.txt` would look like below:

```
[
    {
        "group_name": "default",
        "proxy": [
            "wkenwwins:1000:username:password",
            "uwhsuh:1000:username:password"
        ]
    }
]
```